# Call a Collibra workflow using script task after 15 days from current date

Tags: workflow, collibra

I have two Collibra workflows, lets say WF A which takes response from User1 through User Task on Day 1. On Day 15, I need to call another WF i.e., WF B which assigns the task to different user i.e., User2. Can someone help as I am new to workflows.

Earlier I tried with a Timer Boundary Event but once User1 completes the task, the instance of workflow gets completed. I need User2 to receive the task 15 days after the task gets completed by User1